# Unity, кнопка не работает при зажатии

Tags: c#, unity3d, button

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private int lives;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sr = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
    public void Left()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
        sr.flipX = true;
    }

    public void Right()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
        sr.flipX = false;
    }
}
```

кнопки(влево и вправо) работают только при клике хотя к ним я добавил event trigger, а там pointer down
[image: Unity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PointerDown только отлавливает однократное нажатие. Если нужно имитировать нажатие, то его нужно использовать в паре с PointerUp.

Нужно завести флаг, что кнопка нажата, PointerDown будет устанавливать его, а PointerUp сбрасывать. А в FixedUpdate (раз у тебя через физику сделано) проверять если флаг стоит, то двигаем персонажа. Для другой кнопки аналогично.

```
bool moveRightPressed;
bool moveLeftPressed;

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (moveRightPressed)
    {
        Right();
    }
    else if (moveLeftPressed)
    {
        Left();
    }
}

//для правой кнопки, повесить в EventTrigger

public void OnRightButtonDown ()
{
    moveRightPressed = true;
}

public void OnRightButtonUp ()
{
    moveRightPressed = false;
}

void Right ()
{
    //тут двигаем вправо
}

//для левой кнопки, повесить в EventTrigger

public void OnLeftButtonDown ()
{
    moveLeftPressed = true;
}

public void OnLeftButtonUp ()
{
    moveLeftPressed = false;
}

void Left ()
{
    //тут двигаем влево
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, только в public void OnRightButton Down и Up вы ошиблись и написали moveLeftPressed, но я исправил и всё сработало

Comment: Ага, код поправил.